# Custom meta box data in rss feed

Tags: metabox, rss

Im using WP Alchemy to set up some custom meta boxes. Since these are being used for audio files, when I create a feed the data does not come in and i cannot create a podcast feed for them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it

```
// Add the audio link to the feeds so we can podcast
function feed_customMeta($content) {
global $post, $id, $radioMeta;

  if ( !is_feed() )
    return $content;

 $getRadioLink = '<a href="'.$radioMeta->get_the_value('radioLink').'">Download Audio</a>';

  if( $getRadioLink)
    $content .= $getRadioLink;
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'feed_customMeta');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'feed_customMeta');
```